# How to find index of Python tkinter's OptionMenu index?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am looking for a solution to find the index(number) of the chousen OptionMenu option.
Python 3.8
Values can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you dont care about using dictionaries.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.variable = tk.StringVar()
        self.variable.set('Option 1')
        self.options = {'Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'}
        self.option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.root, self.variable, *self.options)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Button", command=self.on_click)
        self.option_menu.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_click(self):
        choice = self.variable.get()
        index = {'Option 1' : 0, 'Option 2': 1, 'Option 3': 2}[choice]
        print(index)

Window()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just threw tk.OptionMenu, using ttk.Combobox instead